# Problem in taking difference in timestamp

Tags: python, dataframe, for-loop, if-statement, timestamp

I have a timestamp column for 30 seconds resolution for 10 days. I want to take a difference between them, but difference between them should be zero when date changes. I have written below code but it is not giving me the solution i require

```
for i in range(len(df1)-1):
    if (df1.iloc[i+1, 22] == df1.iloc[i, 22]):
        df1.ix[i+1, ['Time']] = df1.iloc[i+1, 24] - df1.iloc[i, 24]
    else:
        df1.ix[i+1, ['Time']] = np.nan
```

I have seperated date and time into sepereate columns
**df1.iloc[i+1, 22]** is the date column, **df1.iloc[i+1, 24]** is the time column

How can i Proceed?

Comment: why did you separate them?

Comment: i thought it will be easy for calculation. il convert it to string and compare dates. if second date is matching with first date il take difference or else return zero. if there is any other idea i am happy to hear it

Comment: there is one more idea i just thought, but it is a lazy one. when date changes, the timedifference becomes negative, i will change it to zero when there is negative value :P

Comment: if you want to calculate the time difference between 2 datetimes you don't need to separate days from hours

Comment: you can directly calculate the difference

Comment: my dataframe have timestamp of many dates. i dont want to take difference at the moment when date changes. i want it to be zero